# Directory traversal attack on SpringBoot

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i'm currently working on a project, and my client has established a vulnerability scan on my application with acunetix tool and it's has given him an alert about Directory traversal attack.
The vulnerability was detected on my static folder that contains all the js/css/images folders, i've used spring security to deny access to those folders but the filter has blocked the access from inside the app, no style and js script can be loaded with this approach.
I've found on the internet that users of spring framework should update the version but i'm using spring boot and i think it's still affected by this vulnerability.
How can i fix this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out [the Pivotal Security page](http://pivotal.io/security) to:

- determine if this vulnerability has already been fixed
- send a repro project to the security team using the email address provided on that page

Note that vulnerability scanners often get things wrong, so just joining a generated report will likely be a false positive.

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it out.